# mySQL & PDO - SELECT WHERE user IS NULL and user = :user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to be able to retrieve the table rows that are Null or have the bound user name. Can someone explain the correct sql statement?

```
$value = $db_site->prepare('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user IS NULL AND user = :user');
$value->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$value->execute();
```

If it matters the retrieved info is then sent through a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use OR instead of AND:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user IS NULL OR user = :user
```

by using AND you are saying that the user column should be null and equal to :user at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to be able to retrieve the table rows that are Null **OR** have the bound user name.
>
> 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user IS NULL **AND** user = :user'

Do you notice the difference? ;-)